# Java Date object parsing precision is off on SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a date as a string `2016-10-07T12:46:23Z` and after parsing to Date object using SimpleDateFormat is converted to `Fri Oct 07 08:46:22 EDT 2016` which is 1 sec precision off. Debugging that code it came that it was parsed to `Fri Oct 07 08:46:22.998 EDT 2016`

SimpleDateFormat to parse as looks like

```
DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.UTC_TIME, "UTC"));
```

and the code to parse looks like

`String dateStr = valuesArray.getString(0);
 values[0] = RESTUtils.DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601.parse(dateStr);`

Any tips how to get proper seconds value after parsing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - that looks extremely unlikely to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `new SimpleTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.UTC_TIME, "UTC"))` **defines an offset not of zero, but 2 milliseconds**, see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.SimpleTimeZone.UTC_TIME), thus explaining the observed result of "Fri Oct 07 08:46:22.998 EDT 2016".

The constant `SimpleTimeZone.UTC` is not intended to indicate an offset (as mandated as first argument to `SimpleTimeZone`-constructor). Its numerical value of "2" is rather a mode to denote how to interprete start or end time parameters for other constructors.

Therefore the correct solution to interprete the trailing "Z" in your input (ISO-8601-notation for zero offset) is:

```
DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use the class `SimpleTimeZone`:

```
DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "UTC"));
```

And if you are on **Java-8**, you could also do this:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2016-10-07T12:46:23Z");
System.out.println(instant); // 2016-10-07T12:46:23Z
System.out.println(Date.from(instant)); // Fri Oct 07 14:46:23 CEST 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the second difference when you add the time zone as UTC using `SimpleTimeZone`, if you comment that part out you will get the exact seconds.

```
String str = "2016-10-07T12:46:24Z";
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
// DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.UTC_TIME, "UTC"));
System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601.parse(str));
```

`SimpleTimeZone` is not meant to be used to define the time zone. Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html)

> SimpleTimeZone is a concrete subclass of TimeZone that represents a
>   time zone for use with a Gregorian calendar. The class holds an offset
>   from GMT, called raw offset, and start and end rules for a daylight
>   saving time schedule. Since it only holds single values for each, it
>   cannot handle historical changes in the offset from GMT and the
>   daylight saving schedule, except that the setStartYear method can
>   specify the year when the daylight saving time schedule starts in
>   effect.

The correct way to set the timezone is by doing the following

```
DATE_FORMAT_ISO8601.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Oh no, standard Java is totally agnostic of leap seconds. And your suggestion ignores the ISO-8601-spec which says that the trailing "Z" has to be handled as zero offset because not setting any timezone means using the default timezone of system which is in most cases not on zero offset.

Comment: For example in my timezone (GMT+2), your suggestion yields a **delta of two full hours compared with the input**, much worse than the 2 milliseconds of the code in the question of OP.

Comment: I have given the link to the documentation in my answer, just follow it. `SimpleTimeZone.UTC` is a magic number and integer constant defined as "2".